# How to link a review from FB API to a page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using FB Webhooks to get reviews of a page, which gives data in the following format 
`{
    "rating": 5,
    "reviewer_id": "1286740178038617",
    "reviewer_name": "Souvik Das",
    "comment_id": null,
    "review_text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ",
    "item": "rating",
    "verb": "add",
    "created_time": 1501152301,
    "open_graph_story_id": "1441952429184057"
}`

The problem here is 'open_graph_story_id' which referenced to the page from this data is coming from, however to get the page data i need an access token of that particular page. I have thousands of page in my DB, therefore it is impractical to employ a brute-force approach.

Comment: Surely that can’t be all the data you’re getting …? This looks like it is just the `changes` entry of the full request data structure.

Comment: Yes maybe... can you please tell why the comment_id is coming null?

Comment: Because what triggered the webhook was _not_ a comment on a rating …?

Comment: Can we get review URL using `open_graph_story_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my data I recived from FB webhook ver 2.9 subcribe " rating":

```
{
"entry": [
    {
        "changes": [
            {
                "field": "ratings",
                "value": {
                    "rating": 5,
                    "reviewer_id": "975746312528574",
                    "reviewer_name": "Trung Nguyễn Văn",
                    "comment_id": null,
                    "review_text": "Hay lắm",
                    "item": "rating",
                    "verb": "add",
                    "created_time": 1501234151,
                    "open_graph_story_id": "1011062825663589"
                }
            }
        ],
        "id": "109934616337310",
        "time": 1501234153
    }
],
"object": "page"
```

}

In this, I use id ( it's page_id)  and find it on DB to get access_token.

Comment: Can we get review URL using `open_graph_story_id`?

Comment: Well you can just append it to facebook.com/, it'll automatically redirect to the correct address.